# What is the use of email in Django Superuser?

Tags: django

Django asks to enter an email of while creating a superuser, What is the primary use of this?

Will there be a security risk in entering a random email address like `test@test.com` or `admin@admin.com` which Django might send privileged communication to?

I checked the Django docs which don't discuss this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A superuser is just an instance of a user with `is_superuser=True`, which gives you all permissions regardless.  There's an `email` field on Django's default `User` model, but you can leave the field blank if you want.

Note that the email addresses for admin users may be used in [error reporting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/error-reporting/#email-reports) when the list of [`ADMINS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#admins) is configured in settings.